# git pull: Unable to create ORIG_HEAD.lock No space left on device

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, diskspace

I'm having an issue where when attempting to perform a "git pull", I receive the following errors message:

> Unable to create '/path/.git/ORIG_HEAD.lock': No space left on device

The thing that's puzzling me is that I definitely have quite a bit of space left on the device:

> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/xvda1      7.8G  2.6G  5.2G  33% /
>
> devtmpfs        7.4G   16K  7.4G   1% /dev
>
> tmpfs           7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /dev/shm
>
> /dev/xvdf       250G  8.5G  242G   4% /path

I'm also witnessing logs being written to on the same device that is being said to be full.

The only thing that comes to mind is that this disk was recently upgraded from 8GB to 250GB over at AWS, and it appears that git believes it's still an 8GB drive?

Output of fdisk -l:

> Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk /dev/xvdf: 268.4 GB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

df -i also shows only 1% used on that volume?

Does this make any sense?  Thanks for any tips and comments you can provide.

Comment: Looks like this issue is back on another webserver.  Looking into it some more, but would value any other input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone encountering the same issue, the way I solved it was to unmount the drive, run xfs_repair on it, re-mount it, and restart the EC2 instance.

Not very elegant, but it saved me the headache.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Linux file systems have to limited ressources: Blocks to write data to, and inodes to write metadata to. If there is no space left on the device, one of the two is completely used, and if you still can write to existing files, then more likely you are out of inodes.

There are some questions about this general problem in the stackoverflow world, some of them here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem

https://serverfault.com/questions/396768/ext4-file-system-max-inode-limit-can-anyone-please-explain

https://superuser.com/questions/585641/changing-max-inode-count-number-in-ext3-filesystem-in-cent-os

Comment: I don't believe I've run out of inodes. Strangely enough the other two web servers in the stack were operating just fine and under the same conditions.  I simply rebuilt the one that was "messing up" and everything is back to normal.  Could this have been a physical problem with the disk? Or error in the partition?